# .sh to run terminal command

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, sh

This is probably insanely simple but I'm sort of new to this and have no idea what I'm doing.
Very simply, I have MouseON.sh that when ran, I want it to open a terminal, run a command, then close the terminal it opened. (yes I know that seems redundant but for my purposes this is what I need). I've googled and looked around this site but can't really find something I can understand due to noobery.

I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
gnome terminal -x sh -c xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Which opens and closes the terminal nicely, but doesn't actually run 'xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0'

Suggestions?

Also, yes I'm aware it's called "MouseON" and setting it to 0 would turn the mouse off, I have it set to that for testing purposes.

I'm also aware there are other ways to turn the mouse on and off but again for my purposes this is what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quote the argument to `-c`? `gnome terminal -x sh -c 'xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0'`

Comment: Bah! You're 100% right. Works perfectly now. THANK YOU.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to open `gnome-terminal` for that ?

Comment: @Serg Please refer to noobery. I'm fairly new to linux and am not a programmer. I don't doubt there's a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

From `man gnome-terminal`:

```
       -x, --execute
                 Execute the remainder of the command line inside the  termi‐
                 nal.
```

When `sh -c xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0` is evaluated in order to be executed, `sh` is interpreted as the executable to be run, and the arguments to `sh` are splitted on spaces; so `xinput` is intepreted as the argument to `sh`'s `-c` option and `set-prop`, `10`, `Device Enabled` and `0` are interpreted as options / arguments to `sh`, and not as options / arguments to `xinput`.

The solution is quoting the `xinput` command using single / double quotes to prevent the command from being splitted on spaces and to make it be interpreted by `sh` as a whole argument to the `-c` option:

```bsh
gnome terminal -x sh -c 'xinput set-prop 10 "Device Enabled" 0'
```

or

```bsh
gnome terminal -x sh -c "xinput set-prop 10 \"Device Enabled\" 0"
```